# Class folder added to build path in Eclipse; still getting errors

Tags: java, eclipse

I have three .class files (that have no .java file) that I'm trying to use in an Eclipse project. I have them in a folder in the project hierarchy and I used "Add Class Folder" under the project properties to add them to the build path. But, my code that's trying to use those classes is still getting a "Foo can not be resolved" error (Foo being the name of one of the classes specified in the .class file). Any idea why this might happen?

Comment: Are there any package declarations? The "Class Folder" needs to be at the root of the package hierarchy. If necessary, you have to create some intermediate directories to match the package structure.

Comment: If there are no package declarations then you will not be able to import them anyway.

Comment: Have you added an import statement for each class, to the top of the Java file where you're trying to use them?